# My Windows 10 Pro is acting as if Hyper-V is enabled despite the fact that I have memory integrity from core isolation turned off?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hyper-v

Months ago, I have installed Bluestacks and HAXM in Android Studio and it worked fine. But due to some reasons, I uninstalled them and now when I want to install them, both of the apps are giving me the same reason. That the Hyper-V is enabled. But, it clearly is turned off in optionalfeatures or Windows Features, and Memory Integrity from Core Isolation of Device Security is also being turned off.

However, the problem still persists. I have searched some solutions but all of them are solved by turning off memory integrity. But in my case, I cannot even turn it on as it would notify me that it is incompatible.

Comment: There are several ways to completely disable Hyper-V on a compatible PC. One would be via PowerShell with the "Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor -All" or "DISM /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V" commands (admin); another via msconfig, and taking the time to uncheck all the Hyper-V services on startup, then reboot your PC. Another still in command line (admin) with "bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off". You might have to disable Secure Boot for one reboot, then go back to UEFI and enable it again. Check "systeminfo.exe" for status then.

Comment: "It is required to have Virtualization enabled for your CPU in your UEFI firmware settings to have Core isolation Memory integrity available." __Brink__ https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/104025-turn-off-core-isolation-memory-integrity-windows-10-a.html "Turn On or Off Core Isolation Memory Integrity using a REG file"

Comment: @vssher SVM is already enabled, and I can ensure that because I can run Virtual OSes in VirtualBox just fine

Comment: @Didier I have tried all the mentioned things, but Android Studio's HAXM installation is still regarding my Windows as Hyper-V is enabled.

Comment: Some settings in the application must cause that. Install the freeware version fo Revo Uninstaller (https://www.revouninstaller.com/fr/revo-uninstaller-free-download/) and thoroughly uninstall Android Studio's HAXM, with no leftovers whatsoever, then reboot your PC and reinstall it from scratch.